# Does Prometheus jmx-exporter hot-reload the configuration file?

Tags: java, jmx, prometheus

does anybody know if jmx_exporter supports configuration file hot-reloading ?    I'm using it to read metrics of a Kafka broker and don't want to restart the broker if the list of metrics changes.
Any idea ?
Thanks
R.

Comment: Looks like it does: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/collector/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JmxCollector.java. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It does, however the list of metrics shouldn't change much.